# Page doesn't load after clicking listview item in Iphone simulator /Jquery Mobile-PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am creating a webapp for iPhone using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. Everything works fine in Safari for Mac and Chrome for Windows.

When I go to the iPhone Simulator the problems begin. I am dynamically populating a listview using the following output line:

```
output += "<li class='elist'> \
            <a href=\"article.html?id="+id+"\" data-transition=\"none\">    \
            <img src=\"img/"+ImageURL+"\" height='70' width='70' />         \
            <h4>"+Title+"</h4>                                              \
            <p>"+month[mMonth]+" "+mDay+", "+mYear+"</p>                    \
            </a> \
            </li>";
```

After the list element has been generated and I click this list element the loading icon shows for ever and it doesn't even load the page. If I try `rel=external` it will defeat the purpose of animation and Jquery mobile.

Any idea why this is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: It seems like Article.html cannot be found by the Iphone simulator. I tried to add href="Article.html" to a link and I still get the same result. I have deleted and added the file back with no luck. I have renamed the file with no luck. WHAT IS GOING ON?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `article.html` file is located in the same directory as the page that links to it?

Also, you are passing a query-string to the new page. How do you parse that query-string in the `article.html` document?

Comment: I am 100% sure the page is on the same folder. On the other hand, I don't think the problem has to do with the parameters I am passing to the article.html page. I tried removing the parameter and I still get the same results. I use the following to parse: 


function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
   vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
 }